# Angularjs Modals and Promises control flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I'm having some issues with the flow of my application. I'm trying to refresh a list when a new item has been created using a modal.

This is what the logic should be:

1. Hit new group button Modal shows up,
2. fill form Submit form, data is sent over to the service
3. Service creates the new group and calls the `getGroup()`
4. getGroups retrieves the new list of groups, the service resolves
5. After the service is done I need to set variables in my main ctrl so the DOM reflects the new change

HTML:

```
<div class="topPanel">
    <div class="topRow">
        <label for="entityDropDown">Select a Group:</label>
        <select id="entityDropDown" ng-model="selectedGroup" ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups" ng-change="getGroupInfo(selectedGroup)"></select>
        <button type="button" class="delGroupBtn btn-danger" ng-disabled="!selectedGroup" ng-click="deleteGroup()">&#10006;</button>
        <button type="button" class="delGroupBtn btn-success" ng-click="newGroup()">New Group</button>
    </div>
    <div class="userGroups" ng-show="selectedGroup">
        <div>
            <label for="entityAvailable">Available Users</label>
            <select id="entityAvailable" multiple ng-model="selectedAvailableUsers" ng-options="u.name for u in availableUsers | orderBy: 'name'"></select>
        </div>
        <div id="moveButtons">
            <button type="button" ng-disabled="!selectedGroup || availableUsers.length === 0 || selectedAvailableUsers.length === 0" ng-click="manageGroup(true)">Add to Group</button>
            <button type="button" ng-disabled="!selectedGroup || assignedUsers.length == 0 || selectedAssignedUsers.length === 0" ng-click="manageGroup(false)">Remove from Group</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="entityAssigned">Users In Group</label>
            <select id="entityAssigned" multiple ng-model="selectedAssignedUsers" ng-options="u.name for u in assignedUsers | orderBy:'name'"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clearfix" />
</div>
```

groupCtrl:

```
$scope.newGroup = function (){
    var d = $q.defer();
    var modalForm = '/Style%20Library/projects/spDash/app/partials/newGroup.html';
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: modalForm,
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'modal',
        controller: newGroupCtrl,
        resolve:{
            newGroup:function (){
                return  $scope.newGroup;
            }
        }       
    });
    $scope.selectedGroup = false;
    $scope.groups = groupService.getGroups();
    d.resolve();
    return d.promise;
};

 /*At first I wanted to set newGroups to return a promise and then manipulate the $scope elements.But I got error then() is not a function of $scope.newGroup so I had to move the scope elements up into the function but now it runs before the service is even done. */

    /*$scope.newGroup.then(function(){
        $scope.selectedGroup = false;
        $scope.groups = groupService.getGroups();
    },
    function(){
        console.log('failed to create new group');
    });*/
```

Modal newGroupCtrl:

```
var newGroupCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, groupService){
    $scope.newGroup = {};

    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log('creating new group');
        console.log($scope.newGroup);
        $modalInstance.close($scope.newGroup);
    }
    $scope.cancel = function (){
        $modalInstance.dismiss('Cancelled group creation');
    };

    $modalInstance.result.then(function (newGroup){
        groupService.createGroup(newGroup);
    }, function (reason){
        console.log(reason);
    }); 
}
```

createGroup Service function:

```
var createGroup = function (newGroup) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var currentUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "Name",
        debug: false
    });

    var promise = $().SPServices({
        operation: "AddGroup",
        groupName: newGroup.name,
        description: newGroup.desc,
        ownerIdentifier: currentUser,
        ownerType: "user",
        defaultUserLoginName: currentUser,
    })

    promise.then(function (){
        console.log('new group created');
        getGroups();
        deferred.resolve();
    },
    function(){
        console.log('failed to create new group');
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Problem: How do I get the main controller to run functionsAFTER the createGroup service function has finished and returned it's promise?**

For example, once the modal calls createGroup service function and that function updates my user list, I need to set these elements in the main groupCtrl:

```
        $scope.selectedGroup = false;
        $scope.groups = groupService.getGroups();
```

Comment: Add a `.then` on the promise?

Comment: Also, chain `.then`s - that `deferred = $q.defer()` is totally uncalled for

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm trying to set selectedGroup to false and $scope.groups AFTER the createGroup service function is done. I'm not sure if I have to return something to the modal ctrl, then to the main or if I can skip to modal ctrl and just go straight to the main. I'm not really sure what to do.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm sorry can you elaborate why it's uncalled for? I thought it was necessary.

Comment: @Batman you can chain promises. You can do `return promise.then(function(){ console.log(..); return getGroups())` instead of the deferred.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Oh okay so the service returns a promise to the newGroupCtrl (modal), but how do I get that promise to return in the primary groupCtrl? The reason is that I need to make changes to the groupCtrls scope elements which aren't in the modal controller.